# R studio cashes when I run jdbc() in RJDBC package

Tags: r, database, oracle

I am trying to connect R with Oracle database, those are the steps that I am following: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/connect-oracle-database-r-rjdbc-tianwei-zhang
However, when I in step 3, R crashes every time when I run jdbc() function.

The class path is correct, I double checked that and the package is loaded.

```
library('rJava')
library('DBI')
library('RJDBC')
jdbcDriver=JDBC("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver", classPath="/Users/username/Documents/JDBC\ connection/OJDBC-Full/ojdbc6.jar")
```

It should works and I dont know how to fix this.

Comment: That's a weird directory for *classPath* argument with space and backslash. Try running outside R Studio (like command line, `Rscript`).